# Should i switch between similar programming languages

Tags: software-industry, career-switch, software-development

I have bachelors in electronics and communication. I got placed in a startup after doing java course from an institute. Now i have 8+ months of experience in c#. I had not learned c# before but as java and c# syntax are similar i am able to write codes (although i take help from internet). Earlier i wrote a servlet in java but my managers say that **syntax does not matter only logic does**, so i was switched to c#.

At present i am uncertain about future as i don't know any language completely. Few of my friends who also got placed talks about career. Some of them thinks that future of web programming would be node.js as front end and back end developer could be the same. Some talks about python will take the server side programming. There is also a consent that .net and c# will get absolute from market and java may also not survive. In internet some blogs suggest not to switch between languages as it will not bring any value to your career.

At present I am working on a desktop application for windows.

I am in a doubt and confusion state. I do not know any guy who is much experienced in software industry. Kindly tell me what should i do for my career, should i learn new language or excel in any of the learned languages.

Comment: Willingness to learn is essential. Learning another language is always a boon. If you do not think it will be permanent, then learn what is necessary, and skim over things that are not. But if you think C# is strategic for your company, then put in the effort and become proficient, because it will pay off on the long term.

Comment: Learning to code is great.  Learning how to BUILD APPLICATIONS AND SERVICES is better.  The trivia and minutia of a particular language are almost irrelevant.  Frameworks improve to abstract the "tricks" into common practices.  I work in C#, now, as well. it is the EIGHTH language I have spent a great deal of time learning, and the "periphery" languages I've dealt with along the way are so numerous I've long ago lost count.  Don't worry about the language.  Worry about your understanding of architecture and design patterns.  Languages change like fashion these days.

Comment: Story time: When I was in school, one of our professor would not grade the code, but the algorithm used. His reasoning was: "Language is a tool, it s not important to know right now how to use the tool if you know why you need this one". And in fact, you can learn about the tool the moment you need that tool, as a engineer, you should worry about how the functionality will work, not the minutiae of how you implement it.

Comment: A previous co-worker recommended me to check job ads periodically of your area and training available from suppliers, this will tell you the trends of your fields.

Comment: Go on codewars.com, do the same problems in both languages. Keep on doing this for a while. C# and Java are very similar. I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 3):

Knowledge of multiple programming languages should not be mutually exclusive. Gaining skill in one language or framework should not deprive you of another. In fact, because many systems are similar in structure and syntax, you may have opportunities to apply your understanding of one language into the practice of another language.

Learn both languages to the point where you would be comfortable to develop in either one. Learn about both front-end and back-end. Become familiar with as many programming languages and frameworks as you can handle.

C++, C#, Java, and Python are commonly used in the software development industry, however there is no single "best" or "most valuable" language. Having a wide breadth of skills means you are flexible. And if you're flexible and able to learn quickly, you have a better chance to impress employers and expand in your career.

Answer (score 3):

Technology is always changing.  Anyone who thinks they can make a lifetime career out of a single language is extremely naive.  To have a successful career as a programmer, you're going to have to keep learning new languages and new platforms for your entire career.  The more languages you learn, the easier each new one will be.  What you don't want to be 10 or 15 years from now is someone who decided at the start of their career that X is the One True Language, and never learned anything else since; only to discover that X's market share has dwindled to a small fraction of what it was and that with only X on your resume that potential employers are afraid that you won't be able to quickly come up to speed with their stack based on Y and Z.

Comment: +1 I retired early, after only 32 years in industry. The languages I was using at the end of that career, in 2002, were Java, Verilog, and Perl. They were released in 1995, 1990, and 1987 respectively. I started work in 1970. If I had picked a One True Language then it would probably have been Fortran.